# $\int _a^{x_1} |\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(s, x_2,...,x_n)|^p ds \le (x_1-a) |\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)|^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

How  to show $\int _a^{x_1} |\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(s, x_2,...,x_n)|^p ds \le (x_1-a) |\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)|^p$, where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(a, x_2,...,x_n)=0$ and $u(a, x_2,...,x_n)=0$.

This question is a step of proof of Poincare inequality, I fail to calculate it, and I feel it is not right,  so ask here, thanks for any help.

I have add the book, but it is written by Chinese.

> [image]

Comment: Which book/online notes are you reading this proof of the Poincare inequality from? The inequality as stated does not feel right, but there may be further context from the proof you are reading that makes it valid.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon   Thanks, I have add the book, but it is written by Chinese. I think I should to find another proof to read, what book do you recommend ?

Comment: Good enough for me, +1. I do not know Chinese , agreed, but I still think I might be able to salvage something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH, found it. There was no way the inequality you wanted was true : I had to see the context and get the answer. There's a hanging variable.

It is this : let us write $dx = dx_1dx_2...dx_n$ for the integral over $Q$. Then the line before the question mark is actually (by definition of $Q$):
$$
d^{p-1}\int_Q \int_{a_1}^{a_1+d} |D_1u(s,x_2,...,x_n)|^p dsdx_1dx_2...dx_n  \\ =d^{p-1} \underbrace{\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}\cdots\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}}_{n \text{ times}} \int_{a_1}^{a_1+d} |D_1u(s,x_2,...,x_n)|^p dsdx_1dx_2...dx_n \\ = d^{p-1}\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d} \left[ \underbrace{\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}\cdots\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}}_{n \text{ times}} |D_1u(s,x_2,...,x_n)|^p dsdx_2...dx_n\right]dx_1 \\ = d^{p-1} \times d \times \left[\underbrace{\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}\cdots\int_{a_1}^{a_1+d}}_{n \text{ times}} |D_1u(s,x_2,...,x_n)|^p dsdx_2...dx_n\right] \\ = d^p \int_Q |D_1u(s,x_2,...,x_n)|^p dsdx_2...dx_n
$$

where the fourth line follows from the fact that the inside integral doesn't depend on $x_1$. So the $d$ term comes from this variable. Finally, if we just call $s = x_1$ now, we get the line you mark $?$ in the author's notes.

Comment: Thanks，really good, haha.

Comment: Yes, at the end of all those integrals it was one bad variable. Finding that out I have a few bad hairs now.

Comment: Don't be care it, you got bald and stronger   ;-)